# Why does the unit vector of form $x_i=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ minimize sum of $x_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, summation

Cauchy-Schwarz implies that for $||\vec{x}||=1, \vec{y}=(1,\ldots,1)\in\mathbb R^n,\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = \pm\sqrt{n}$ if $\vec{x}=\pm{k}\vec{y}$. This implies that $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}k\\\vdots\\k\end{bmatrix}$.

Why does it follow that $nk^2=1$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ is minimized where $k=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}$?

I've seen the beginnings of a proof that shows $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i)^2\leq{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$, or something like $\int_0^1(f(x)\mathrm{d}x)^2\leq\int_0^1f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x$, but I may have written it down wrong. How do these inequalities show $k=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}?$

Comment: Your notation is unclear. Do you mean to say that
$$\max_{\|x\|_2 = 1} x^T e = \sqrt n\ ?$$
($e = (1,1,\ldots, 1)\in\mathbb R^n$)

Comment: Possibly - forgive my ignorance - what is $x^T$? The trace? The transpose?

Comment: The transpose. $x^T e = \sum_{i=1}^n e_ix_i = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

Comment: maybe [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/97rqv071nryw26b/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-28%20at%201.42.04%20PM.png?dl=0) will clarify?

Comment: Yes. The correct notation is either $y = e$ as I noted, or $y=(1,1,\ldots,1)\in\mathbb R^n$. $1_1, \ldots, 1_n$ is bogus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegedly the referenced theorem is a more general version of CSI:

> For $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$,
>   $$\langle x,y\rangle \le \|x\|_2 \|y\|_2$$
>   With equality if and only if $x\parallel y$, i.e. $x=\lambda y$ for some $\lambda \in\mathbb R_+$ or $y=0$.

Thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \langle x, e\rangle \le \|x\|_2 \|e\|_2 = \|x\|_2 \sqrt n = \sqrt n$$
with equality if and only if $x = \lambda e$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.
The constraint $\|x\|_2 = 1$ now implies $\lambda = \frac1{\sqrt n}$. Analogously with $y = -e$ you get $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = -\sqrt n, \|x\|_2 = 1 \Rightarrow x = -\frac1{\sqrt n} e$.